# NextJS unable to load types while seeding to a database

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have directory structure as follows

```
app/
├─ page.tsx
├─ lib/
│  ├─ definitions.ts
├─ scripts/
│  ├─ seed.ts
```

definitions.ts

```js
export type User = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
};
```

I'm trying to export type user to seed.ts and run it to populate a database.

seed.ts

```js
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const { users } = require("../lib/placeholder");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

import { User } from "../lib/definitions";


const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true,
});

async function seedUsers() {
  const client = await pool.connect();
  try {
    await client.query('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"');

    // Create the "users" table if it doesn't exist
    await client.query(`
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
                name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                password TEXT NOT NULL
            )
        `);

    console.log(`Created "users" table`);

    // Insert data into the "users" table
    const insertedUsers = await Promise.all(
      users.map(async (user:User) => {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
        await client.query(
          `
                    INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, password)
                    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
                    ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING
                `,
          [user.id, user.name, user.email, hashedPassword]
        );
        return user;
      })
    );

    console.log(`Seeded ${insertedUsers.length} users`);

    return insertedUsers;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error seeding users:", error);
    throw error;
  } finally {
    client.release(); // release the client back to the pool
  }
}

async function main() {
  try {
    await seedUsers();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(
      "An error occurred while attempting to seed the database:",
      error
    );
  } finally {
    await pool.end(); // close all the clients in the pool
  }
}

main();
```

I ran the seed file using the following command

```bash
node -r dotenv/config app/scripts/seed.ts
```

It is throwing this error
^^^^^^

```bash
import { User } from "../lib/definitions";

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v20.9.0
```

I tried 'require("../lib/definitions")' but it is not infering the type.

It worked fine when I removed the type definitions but that is just a fix and not a solution. Tried require("../lib/definitions") for User but it is inferred as type any.